# modifying a return variable in dafny

Tags: dafny

so I have a method in dafny that takes in an array a, and returns the sorted version, b. In my code, b := a, and then the in-place insertion-sort happens on b. However, whenever I modify b, I get the error that an "assignment may update an array element not in the enclosing context's modifies clause". I am assuming this is because I haven't told dafny I will be in-place modifying b. How do I fix this?

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in Dafny are *references* to array elements. (This is also the case in C, Java, C#, and various other languages.) The assignment `b := a;` copies the reference, but does not copy the elements. You have two choices.

One choice is to create a new array that eventually will hold the sorted elements. To do that, allocate a new array:

```
b := new int[a.Length];
```

If you also want to copy the elements of `a` into the new array `b`, then do:

```
b := new int[a.Length](i requires 0 <= i < a.Length reads a => a[i]);
```

or

```
b := new int[a.Length];
forall i | 0 <= i < a.Length {
  b[i] := a[i];
}
```

Under this choice, the caller will still have a reference to the original array, which will be intact. Through the method's out-parameter, the caller will also get a reference to the new (sorted) array.

The other choice is to modify the original array. Since this affects the caller, you need to write a specification that tells the caller about this. That's done by adding

```
modifies a
```

to your method's specification. Under this choice, there's no reason to declare the out-parameter `b`, since there is only one array and `a` references it.